# TableView not appearing after setting the constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a UITableView in my storyboard. I am trying to setup constraints for it in my view controller. After running the application it's not showing up at all. it's only working when i don't run the constraints. here are my constraints.

```
    func tableviewsConstraints(){
        homeTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        homeTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        homeTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        homeTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        homeTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        homeTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: homeTableView.rowHeight * 3).isActive = true
        self.view.addSubview(homeTableView)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
tableviewsConstraints()
```

Comment: turns out the height anchor is not working. how do i make my tableview height equal to 3 tableview row/cell height

Comment: It is a bit confusing. Are you adding the tableView programatically or it is already present in the storyboard and you're adding the constraints via code? Please clarify.

Comment: it is already present in the storyboard and I am adding the constraints via code. The issue that i am facing is the height constraint. I want it to be equal to 3 rows height. how do i do that.

Comment: Where have you set the rowHeight of the tableview?

Comment: i haven't. i thought it's already set in the storyboard. how do i get the height of it from the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `homeTableView` as the `view's` `subview` before adding the `constraints` to it. And use a constant value when setting the `height` of `tableView`, i.e.

```
func tableviewsConstraints(){
    self.view.addSubview(homeTableView) //here....

    homeTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    homeTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    homeTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    homeTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    homeTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    let rowHeight: CGFloat = 100.0 //here....
    homeTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: rowHeight * 3).isActive = true
}
```

Change the `rowHeight` value as per your requirement.

Comment: I had set my tableview rowheight manually in storyboard and set     homeTableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableview.rowheight * 3).isActive = true. it worked

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the outlet of the table view if you have it in the storyboard? Then why you need to subview? If you're creating table view programmatically then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311714/how-to-add-programmatic-constraints-to-a-uitableview).